# SSIS execution and deployment error "System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly"

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've a few SSIS deployed to SQL 2012 since last year, all up and running without any issue. This error started to prompt

```
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "set_system_informations":   
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' 
threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The paging file is too small for this operation to complete. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800705AF)  
System.IO.FileLoadException:      
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..cctor()  
System.TypeInitializationException:      
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)     
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.SystemInformations.SetSystemInformations(SqlInt64 operationId) 
 .  Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
```

It just failed to run, I tried to deploy again to SQL and similar error appear as follows

```
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "deploy_project_internal": 
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' 
threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The paging file is too small for this operation to complete. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800705AF)
System.IO.FileLoadException: 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..cctor()
System.TypeInitializationException: 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ServerConnectionControl.GetOperationInfo(SqlInt64 operation_id, OperationType type, ServerOperationStatus status, Int64& object_id)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ServerConnectionControl.checkParameters(SqlInt64 object_id, SqlInt64 operation_id, OperationType type)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ServerApi.DeployProjectInternal(SqlInt64 deployId, SqlInt64 versionId, SqlInt64 projectId, SqlString projectName)
. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
```

I've no problem to run the SSIS from the VS2017(SSDT) directly, just can't deploy and get it run on server. I'm not sure what is the root cause of this, all running fine yesterday and start throwing error today.

Anyone encounter this issue before?

Comment: _The paging file is too small for this operation to complete._ Sounds like the machine executing the SSIS packages is running out of memory. Can you increase the size of the swap file/s (aka. paging file/s)?

Answer (score 0):

You might have referenced a different version of `System.Configuration`. It could be added as a dependency by another library. It is possible that the version number has jumped during this time and you are referencing older versions. Anyway, you can overwrite the version in your csproj.